# ArcGIS Geoprocessing - how to set a condition for data

Tags: python, arcgis

I would like to write a script in Python which takes data and does some things with it.

So far, I have written the following code :

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\wody.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
bufferList = []
for fc in fcList:
   if fc == "RZEKI":
       arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc + "Buffer", "200 meters")
       bufferList.append(fc + "Buffer")
```

Now, I would like to take RIVERS (RZEKI) only if river is longer than SOMETHING (they do not give data in meters but in units, so I just want to see an example seems like river_long > WHATEVER)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: ask over at [gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com).  Much more likely to get responses specific to ArcGIS.

Comment: thanks ! i'll move there my post